# How do you get checkbox selections from a CustomTreeCtrl

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm working with a CustomTreeCtrl with checkboxes and I can't figure out how to determine which checkboxes are selected.  I looked at http://xoomer.virgilio.it/infinity77/wxPython/Widgets/wx.TreeCtrl.html#GetSelection and put this together:

```
import string
import os
import sys
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl as CT

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "CustomTreeCtrl Demo")        

        custom_tree = CT.CustomTreeCtrl(self, agwStyle=wx.TR_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        root = custom_tree.AddRoot("The Root Item")

        for y in range(5):
            last = custom_tree.AppendItem(root, "item %d" % y)

            for z in range(5):
                item = custom_tree.AppendItem(last,  "item %d" % z, ct_type=1)

            self.Bind(CT.EVT_TREE_ITEM_CHECKED, self.ItemChecked)

    def ItemChecked(self, event):
            print("Somebody checked something")
            print(event.GetSelections())

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = MyFrame(None)
app.SetTopWindow(frame)
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

When I check a box, I get the Traceback: "AttributeError: 'TreeEvent' object has no attribute 'GetSelections'"  Any suggestions on how to read which boxes are selected would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `event` object in question doesn't have a `GetSelections` method. It does have a `GetSelection`, which will tell you which item was selected at that event. If you want to get all of the selected items inside `ItemChecked`, rename `custom_tree` to `self.custom_tree` and then you're allowed to call `self.custom_tree.GetSelections()` inside `ItemChecked`.

If in future you want to know what kind of methods are available for some event object, you can put `print(dir(event))` in your handler.

The custom tree control doesn't have a method to get the checked items. One thing that you could do is create a `self.checked_items` list in your frame, and maintain it in your `ItemChecked` method. This list could hold either the string values for the items or the items themselves. For instance,

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # ....
        self.checked_items = []
        # ....

    def ItemChecked(self, event):
        if event.IsChecked():
            self.checked_items.append(event.GetItem())
            # or to store the item's text instead, you could do ...
            # self.checked_items.append(self.custom_tree.GetItemText(event.GetItem()))
        else:
            self.checked_items.remove(event.GetItem())
            # or ... 
            # self.checked_items.remove(self.custom_tree.GetItemText(event.GetItem()))
```

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful.  However, the GetSelection method returns which item was selected, not checked.  Do you know if there is a similar method to find which boxes are checked?

Comment: There is no method to do that. I would either manage a list that you add/remove to when you check items or iterate over the items and us IsChecked to find the ones that are checked.