# How to get the checked items of customtreectrl in wxpython?

Tags: wxpython

I am using customtreectrl in my GUI. The items of customtreectrl have a checkbox with them. I want to get those items from customtreectrl which are checked. I also want to get those items which are unchecked and prior they were checked. Customtreecontrol can provide the items which are selected using *GetSelection()* or *GetSelections()* methods but there is no method available for getting checked items. I came up with the following solution:
[How do you get checkbox selections from a CustomTreeCtrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10857090/how-do-you-get-checkbox-selections-from-a-customtreectrl)
but there is a problem that if condition in *ItemChecked(self,event)* method is never reached even if I have some of the items of customtreectrl checked. In other words, whether or not the customtreectrl items are checked *event.IsChecked()* always returns *False*. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrea Gavana (the creator of the CustomTreeCtrl) actually wrote a little function you could use to do this very thing on the wxPython mailing list:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wxpython-users/6kx752Q26AI

I took the example you linked to in your question and combined it with Andrea's code to come up with the following example:

```
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.customtreectrl as CT

########################################################################
class MyCustomTree(CT.CustomTreeCtrl):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        """"""
        CT.CustomTreeCtrl.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kw)

    def GetCheckedItems(self, itemParent=None, checkedItems=None):
        if itemParent is None:
            itemParent = self.GetRootItem()

        if checkedItems is None:
            checkedItems = []

        child, cookie = self.GetFirstChild(itemParent)

        while child:

            if self.IsItemChecked(child):
                checkedItems.append(child)

            checkedItems = self.GetCheckedItems(child, checkedItems)
            child, cookie = self.GetNextChild(itemParent, cookie)

        return checkedItems

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "CustomTreeCtrl Demo")
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        custom_tree = MyCustomTree(panel)
        self.custom_tree = custom_tree
        root = custom_tree.AddRoot("The Root Item")

        for y in range(5):
            last = custom_tree.AppendItem(root, "item %d" % y)

            for z in range(5):
                item = custom_tree.AppendItem(last,  "item %d" % z, ct_type=1)

            self.Bind(CT.EVT_TREE_ITEM_CHECKED, self.ItemChecked)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Find Checked Items")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.getCheckedItems)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(custom_tree, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

    def ItemChecked(self, event):
        print("Somebody checked something")

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def getCheckedItems(self, event):
        """"""
        checked_items = self.custom_tree.GetCheckedItems()
        for item in checked_items:
            print item.GetText()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with event.IsChecked() always returning False. Problem was solved with event.GetItem().IsChecked().